# Python find HTML tag position

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml

I need to find position or full text of the tag using `lxml.html`.
For example:

```
[some html code] </body > [some html code]
```

I need to return: `</body >` OR position of this text.

How can I do that? Code below doesn't work.

```
page = fromstring(html)
for s in page.findall('.//body'):
    print s.tag, s.text, s.attrib
```

Comment: It is not clear what "position or full text of the tag" means. `</body>` is the end tag of the `body` element. And what is position? Do you mean line number?

Answer (score 0):

I have defined a python function below which will search for given string in the given file and prints the line number and the line content when the string is found.

```
def find_position(word, file):
    line_number = 0
    for line in open(file):
        line_number += 1
        if word in line:
            print "%d - %s" % (line_number, line)
```

Here word takes word to be searched as a string and file takes path of the file as string. I have given example below.

```
find_position("body", "/home/user/page1.html")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
24 - <body>
28 - </body>
```